# data insert into multiple table in yii

Tags: mysql, yii

I have Two Tables student and studentdetails

```
student table :
id,
student_id

studentdetails :
id,
student_id
name
```

I have a one controller of student details and one model of student and another student details and one view of student details

i need when user fills the form of student details there should first entry in student table and a student_id of student table  then enters into studentdetails table in yii
.

Comment: so what is the problem?)

Comment: when i fills the studentdetails form data got insert into studentdeatils table but not not in student table

Comment: can you please add some code of Views?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are facing the problem with the student_id field.

**I hope, required task is:** before going to enter the student details choose the student id from the student table

For that, replace student_id field (first filed in your student_details form) with dropdown

```
      <?php
      $list = CHtml::listData(Student::model()->findAll(array('order' => 'student_id')), 'student_id', 'student_id'); 
      // echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'student_id', $list);
      echo CHtml::dropDownList('student_id', $model, $list);
      ?>
```

Now student will choose his id and fills the details.

Comment: I am generating the student id when the user fills up the form

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try using the method `afterSave` in model.It will do a pretty job for you

Comment: It is still not working i have two models for both student and student details one controller of students detail i have to save data on both the table simultaneously from one controller

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function actionCreate()
{
   $model = new StudentDetails;
   $smodel = new Student;
   // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
   $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
   if(isset($_POST['StudentDetails']))
   {
      $model->attributes=$_POST['StudentDetails'];
      if($model->save())
      {
        $sid = $model->id;
        $Student = StudentDetails::model()->findByAttributes(array('id'=>$sid));

        $smodel->student_id = $Student->student_id;
        $smodel->save();
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
      }
    }
    $this->render('create',array(
    'model'=>$model,
    ));
 }
```

Comment: @nitin if my answer is little useful to you. i would be glad if you will accept and voteup my answer. so someone can use in future if they want to do the same

Answer (score 0):

Keep like this method on StudentDetails model.

```
public function afterSave() {
        if($this->isNewRecord){
            $studentDetails = new StudentDetails();
            $studentDetails->student_id = $this->id;
            $studentDetails->name = STUDENT_NAME ;// from Yii::app()->user->id OR $_POST or other ; 
            $studentDetails->save();
        }
        return parent::afterSave();
    }
```